# Display value from one cell in Column O based on value found InStr search of separate cell in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this site and others to get this project up and running but I have hit a brick wall. What I am doing is importing (copying) columns c - h from a particular workbook (ImportConvert.xlsx) and pasting them into columns a - f of ControlBook.xlsm. THen I copy rows a -c of a third workbook (Clients.xlsx) and paste those columns in columns m - o of ControlBook.xlsm. Both are on the same worksheet. I was able to get that far from the tutorials I have read so far and thank all for that info. The next thing I set out to accomplish is searching each value in column B of the worksheet with each value in column O to see if the value in Column O is contained within the string value in Column B. When a match is found, I want the value in Column O to display in column g.

When I execute the code it processes from start to finish, but will not display the value in column g.

Here is the code:

```
Sub StartProcess()

Dim wbk As Workbook

    strDataFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ImportConvert.xlsx"
    strMasterFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ControlBook.xlsm"
    strClientFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Clients.xlsx"

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strDataFile)

        With wbk.Sheets("Data")
            Range("c:h").Copy
        End With


    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strMasterFile)

        With wbk.Sheets("Deposits")
            Range("a:f").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With

        wbk.Save
        wbk.Close

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strClientFile)

        With wbk.Sheets("ActivePayee")
            Range("a:c").Copy
        End With

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strMasterFile)

        With wbk.Sheets("Clients")
            Range("m:o").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With

Dim rngSub As Range
Dim rngSrch As Range

For Each rngSub In Range("o2:o1000")
    For Each rngSrch In Range("b2:b1000")
        If InStr(rngSrch, rngSub) > 0 Then
            rngSrch.Offset(, 5) = rngSub.Value
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

This is not the most elegant solution but the person I am trying to help is impatient and just wants it NOW (no regard to built properly). I will go back after he has calmed down and learn a more elegant way to get this project built. I just want to give this guy something to keep him from being so panicky.

I come at this with minimal VBA exposure, but I am familiar with programming via PhP, mySQL, etc. I fumbled around with VBA in the late 90s and early 2000s, but haven't been exposed to VBA in a long time.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

All your `Range(...)` references may be refering to the wrong `Sheet`s.  Without a qualifier `Range` on its own refers to `Activesheet.Range`

Change

```
With wbk.Sheets("Data")
    Range("c:h").Copy
End With
```

to

```
With wbk.Sheets("Data")
    .Range("c:h").Copy
End With
```

Similarly for all other uses of `Range`

And

```
For Each rngSub In Range(...)
```

to

```
For Each rngSub In wrk.Worksheets("YourName").Range(...)
```